# Android NumberPicker OnScroll

Tags: java, android

у меня есть два NumberPicker, мне нужно чтобы при прокрутке второго прокручивался и первый, так как это должен быть один обьект, однако не нашел пиккера который мог бы две строки отображать, помогите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать.

Comment: `setValue` на первом при изменении второго использовать пробовали?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Пробовал все хорошо, однако хотелось бы более плавно

Comment: Взгляните на этот вопрос на [английской версии сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500852/how-to-change-numberpickers-value-with-animation) Если поможет - переведите и выложите тут как ответ на собственный вопрос. Будет Вам жирнейший плюс в карму:)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov К сожалению єто не то что я хочу получить. Мне нужно как-то синхронизировать прокрутку

Comment: Хммм, а если `scrollBy` в сочетании с `onScrollChanged`?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov К сожалению это тоже не помогло